# How to read a .csv file for "training category" with pytorch if all images are in one folder?

Tags: image, machine-learning, pytorch, torchvision

In [this tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/transfer_learning_tutorial.html), they use the following code to read the datasets:

```py
data_dir = 'data/hymenoptera_data'
image_datasets = {x: datasets.ImageFolder(os.path.join(data_dir, x),
                                          data_transforms[x])
                  for x in ['train', 'val']}
dataloaders = {x: torch.utils.data.DataLoader(image_datasets[x],
                                              batch_size=4,
                                              shuffle=True,
                                              num_workers=4)
               for x in ['train', 'val']}
```

In that code, the png dataset is separated in different folders.

The name of each folder means the category of the png file in the folder.

---

I am in a situation where:

- all png files are in a single folder;
- the category of each png file is recorded in a train.csv file.

How can I implement the code with the above function `datasets.ImageFolder`?

Comment: You will probably need to implement your own dataset class. At minimum you just needs to implement `__getitem__` and `__len__`. You probably want to load the CSV file during `__init__` and load your data during `__getitem__`. To make it a little easier you could derive a class from `ImageFolder` and overload the `__init__` method to create the list of images and labels from your csv file rather than a directory structure. I'm this latter case you would need to make sure you set any class members used internally by the `__getitem__` and `__len__` methods of `ImageFolder`

Comment: Some related tips in this tutorial: https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/data_loading_tutorial.html